# estoy haciendo Un Programa que repita 15 veces un nombre (utilizando do-while) en java , pero no me da el resultado

Tags: java, netbeans-11.3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int I=1;
        String N;
        N=NOM1.getText();
        do
        {   
            I++; 
        }
        while(I<10);
         this.NOMBS.setText(String.valueOf(N));
```

Comment: declara las variables en minúscula y uso solo al inicio las mayúsculas cuando nombres clases..al iniciar,el while debe ser(i<=10) debido a que estas iniciándolo en 1, y por ultimo lo que se repetirá debe ir dentro del do

Comment: Primero el this.NOMBS.setText(String.valueOf(N)) debe ir dentro del do, segundo el bucle está mal hecho con i<10 y tercero con this.NOMBS.setText(String.valueOf(N)) no vas a escribir 15 veces el nombre en el textfield porque así le estás cayendo encima al valor que ya tenía el textfield y sólo se va a mostrar el nombre una vez, no se va a repetir, tienes que concatenar los, ahh y por último, no entiendo la necesidad del String.valueOf(N) si N ya es String